# Can someone help me understand the question? Its Linear Equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, fractions

Decide whether the given number is a solution to the equation.

$2x + 3x + 2= 10$; $x = \frac{8}{5}$

Is $x = \frac{8}{5}$ a solution?

Help, I don't understand the question and have no idea how to even check if the solution is true or false.

Comment: Welcome to the MSE. Did you study the first degree equations? :-) $2x+3x=5x$ and $10-2=8$. Hence $x=8/5$. Just it is unique.

Comment: Thank you! Wow lol. It so simple when you see it. I honestly don't remember learning this in school >.<

Comment: Your question suggests you need to re-familiarize yourself with some of the very basics of algebra: what is an equation, what is a variable, what does it mean to evaluate an equation that contains variables. Even if you get an answer from Math.SE I suggest you discuss your confusion with this problem with your teacher/professor. I’d be concerned that you’ll only have further issues as you progress as these things are fundamental.

Comment: Thank you! I don't go back to school until August but I'm starting an accelerated course that starts with pre-alg and moving at my own pace towards intermediate alegebra at a community college. It's weird because I can solve certain problems but don't remember the names of terms and whatnot. Most are muscle memory but I can't seem to remember how to do the work correctly. I passed exponents, the order of operations, and inequality, and the second phase is where I'm stuck at which is: Variables, Expressions, and Equations. I have studied at Khan academy but honestly Idk where to start.

Comment: Gotcha! Well we’re all here to help as you progress! Best wishes and much success in your studies — be sure to always use all your resources — classmates, teachers, and us — math is a team sport — we’ve all been where you are :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=\dfrac85$ then $2x=\dfrac{16}5$ and $3x=\dfrac{24}5$,

so $2x+3x+2=\dfrac{16}5+\dfrac{24}5+2=\dfrac{16+24}5+2=8+2=10$,

so $x=\dfrac85$ is a solution.

Comment: so when I multiply 8/5 and 2 I don't have to change the denominator to 10? Omg thank you I'm just barely learning this. So when there's a whole number, turning the whole number into a fraction would be 2 = 2/1 ?

Comment: This is what I did:

2x + 3x + 2= 10
7x + 2 = 10
2 times 8/5 = 16/10 
3 times 8/5 = 40/15

Comment: $2\times\dfrac85=\dfrac{2\times8}5=\dfrac{16}5$